# Copy and Paste the Row based on condition in another Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been looking on this website and others for an answer but can't find anything relevant and was wondering if someone could help please.

I've using **Apps Script - Google Sheets**.

The main sheet was called "M-Front". So it got quotation number with revision number. If new quotation, the revision will be zero. If we revise the quotation once, the revision number will be 1.

For example, GE-2108-0271-Rev.0 is **new** quotation.
If we revise once, it would be GE-2108-0271-Rev.1.

I have other sheet called "M-Items".

Let say for GE-2108-0271-Rev.0, we have three rows for that quotation number represent three items for that quotation.

My intention is , if new revision was made in "M-Front". It will be GE-2108-0271-Rev.1. But how to detect the last row from "M-Front" quotation number and in "M-Items" we copy and paste the rows. In this case, 3 rows/items. and make the quotation in "M-Items" from GE-2108-0271-Rev.0 to GE-2108-0271-Rev.1.

[M-Front](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibweO.png)
[M-Items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAO7a.png)

The Script i've stuck

```
function CopyRange() {
var sourcespread = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Zgs1jzjIeaBpd5Ms7emQgxhVJBMtlEOlDNDfxlhSRiY'); //replace with source ID
  var sourcesheet = sourcespread.getSheetByName('M-Front'); //replace with source Sheet tab name
  var destspread = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Zgs1jzjIeaBpd5Ms7emQgxhVJBMtlEOlDNDfxlhSRiY'); //replace with destination ID
  var destsheet = destspread.getSheetByName('M-Items'); //replace with destination Sheet tab name
  var testrange = sourcesheet.getRange('M:M').getLastRow;
  var testvalue = (testrange.getValues());
  var data = [];
  var j =[];

  for (i=0;i<testvalue.length;i++) {
    if (testvalue[i] /= 0) {
    data.push.apply(data,sourcesheet.getRange('A:A').getValues());
  //Copy matched ROW numbers to j
    j.push(i);
}  
}
  //Copy data array to destination sheet
  destsheet.getRange(destsheet.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand what is it that you want to achieve - do you simply want to have one entry in "M-Front" with the latest revision? So in this situation you would only have one entry which is this one "GE-2108-0271-Rev.1"?

Comment: @ale13 
It something looks like this:

Step 1 : Triggered the new row, Check whether the Column M:M is not Zero. If else, stop. 
For your information the column M;M is the revision number at the back. If quotation number  GE-2108-0271-Rev.0. column M:M is zero. if  GE-2108-0271-Rev.1,      the column M:M is 1.

Step 2 : At M-Front, check column A:A

Step 3 : At M-Items, check row which its Column A:A =  [column A:A (M-Front)] AND  [column M:M (M-Front)] = [column C:C (M-Items)-1]

Step 4 :

Comment: @ale13 

 Step 4 : Select Step 3 which is TRUE, copy and paste at the same sheet (M-Items) to the bottom AND column C increment by 1 and quotation number increment as well.

Comment: Please add those information to your question and provide some screenshots that are easy for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the below script:

```
function CopyRange() {
  var sourcespread = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Zgs1jzjIeaBpd5Ms7emQgxhVJBMtlEOlDNDfxlhSRiY'); //replace with source ID
  var sourcesheet = sourcespread.getSheetByName('M-Front'); //replace with source Sheet tab name
  var destsheet = sourcespread.getSheetByName('M-Items'); //replace with destination Sheet tab name
  var mcol= sourcesheet.getRange('M1:M').getValues();
  var acol = sourcesheet.getRange('A1:A').getValues();
  var ccol = destsheet.getRange('C1:C').getValues();
  var acol2 = destsheet.getRange('A1:A').getValues();
  var mvalues = mcol.filter(String);
  var avalues = acol.filter(String);
  var cvalues = ccol.filter(String);
  var avalues2 = acol2.filter(String);

  for (let i=1; i<mvalues.length; i++) {
    if (mvalues[i][0] != 0) {
      if (avalues[i][0] == avalues2[i][0] && mvalues[i][0] == cvalues[i][0] - 1)
        var valuescopy = sourcesheet.getRange("RANGE_FOR_THE_VALUES_TO_COPY").getValues();
        destsheet.getRange("RANGE_WHERE_TO_PASTE").setValues(valuescopy);
        cvalues[i][0]++;
    }
  }
}
```

It is important to note the following points:

- `getLastRow` will return the last row for the entire range - this means that the rows which have no values are also included this;

In order to retrieve the rows which contain a value, the `filter` has been used.

- `getValues` method will return a 2D array, so you will have to access an element in this way `array[i][j]`.

Moreover, please bear in mind that you will have to adjust the ranges properly such that they match your needs accordingly; more specifically, the range from where you want to copy the values and also the destination range.

#### Reference

- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet.html#getLastRow());
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#getValues());
- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)).